# Strep in Siem Reap, Cambodia

Tags: international-travel, health, cambodia, siem-reap

I have strep throat in Siem Reap, Cambodia. I've had a pretty bad fever when not taking Ibuprofen, and I have a painful swollen throat with white bacterial mats.

I also have had other problems, which I think stemmed from stupid decisions (not eating/drinking enough) that I have changed.

How do I get penicillin? Can I just go to a pharmacy or do I have to find a special doctor? Will they understand "penicillin" or do I need someone to write me a message in Khmer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't have to see a doctor to get penicillin in Cambodia, I got some antibiotics from a nurse on Koh Rong. And pharmacy staff will definitely understand "penicillin".

Still, it might be a good idea to see a doctor anyway instead of self-diagnosing and self-medicating.

Best ask your hotel/hostel's staff, they should know a doctor who speaks English.

Comment: (Since this thread is active, I figured I'd describe how this concluded) I used penicillin from a local pharmacist, but it was ineffective.  My next stop was South Korea, so I saw a doctor there who confirmed my diagnosis and prescribed mouthwash and a cocktail which included antibiotics, vitamins, fever reducer, and pain killer.  The whole experience was faster, easier, and even cheaper without insurance than in the US with insurance.

Answer (score 2):

You should wait a couple days and if it doesn't heal by itself take a course of oral antibiotics penicillin or amoxicillin, any pharmacy can sell you these for 1-2 dollars. Be sure to complete the entire recommended course (google) even if you feel better, as multiple antibiotic resistant bacteria are a huge problem in Cambodia. I had a similar issue and did not complete the full course, and ending  up bringing back multiple resistant bacteria to Europe, so this is really serious.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to U-care pharmacy, they will have a doctor to consult your disease before you can purchase the medicine. You can find the U-care pharmacy of the East corner of Pub Street or another place along of Sivutha Street.